# Text/Icon Radio Button Name?

Tags: interface-design, terminology, ios, apple

[image]

Does anyone know the official definition for these buttons in the attached image (taken from the Apple Store app)? They're basically radio buttons with an icon and/or text in them, but can't seem to find any documentation on them.

I've looked in the iOS guidelines as well, unless I'm looking in the wrong section. Also if anyone knows, is there an Android counterpart?

Comment: I see a minimum of 18 buttons there... perhaps a bit more specitivity would help?

Comment: I meant the button in general where it's a radio selectable with text and/or an icon, but we'll go ahead with with the two buttons under Finish (Silver/Space Gray) for specifics.

Answer (score 1):

There's no common name for this sort of set of inputs to my knowledge.

I would call it stylized radio buttons. They are likely inputs with button labels and the actual input hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There's no special name for buttons with icons on the inside. People on the internet call it a button with icons.

Comment: This is not the correct name for the *buttons*

Comment: I mean icons in buttons like icon of glass magnifier for search button

Comment: Right, but that's not what the original poster (OP) is looking for. As such, your answer isn't helpful to the poster

Comment: Edited post. There's no special name for it.